# With Python: My recursive function is way to slow

Tags: python, recursion

I want to program the following (I've just start to learn python):

```
f[i]:=f[i-1]-(1/n)*(1-(1-f[i-1])^n)-(1/n)*(f[i-1])^n+(2*f[0]/n);
```

with `F[0]=x`, `x` belongs to `[0,1]` and `n` a constant integer.

My try:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
N=20
n=100
h=0.01
T=np.arange(0, 1+h, h)
def f(i):
    if i == 0:
        return T
    else:
        return f(i-1)-(1./n)*(1-(1-f(i-1))**n)-(1./n)*(f(i-1))**n+2.*T/n
pl.figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=80)
pl.plot(T,f(N), color="red",linestyle='--', linewidth=2.5)
pl.show()
```

For `N=10` (number of iterations) it returns the correct plot fast enough, but for `N=20` it keeps running and running (more than 30 minutes already).

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your run time is so slow is the fact that, like the simplistic calculation of the nth fibonacci number it runs in **exponential time** (in this case 3^n). To see this, before F[i] can return it's value, it has to call f[i-1] 3 times, but then each of *those* has to call F[i-2] 3 times (3*3 calls), and then each of *those* has to call F[i-3] 3 times (3*3*3 calls), and so on. In this example, as others have shown, this can be calculated simply in linear time. That you see it slow for N = 20 is because your function has to be called 3^20 = 3486784401 times before you get the answer!

Comment: You're off by about 50%. Defining g(n) as the number of times the function `f` is called in evaluating `f(n)`, it's easy to see that g(n)=3*g(n-1)+1, with g(0)=1. Expanding this out yields g(n)=(3^(n+1)-1)/2. In the case of N=20, the function will be called 5230176601 times.

Comment: I agree ... my calculation was too hasty (and essentially ignores f(0)). Though for the benefit of the OP this is still exponential

Answer (score 2):

You calculate `f(i-1)` three times in a single recursion layer - so after the first run you "know" the answer but still calculate it two more times. A naive approach:

```
fi_1 = f(i-1)
return fi_1-(1./n)*(1-(1-fi_1)**n)-(1./n)*(fi_1)**n+2.*T/n
```

But of course we can still do better and cache **every** evaluation of f:

```
cache = {}
def f_cached(i):
    if not i in cache:
        cache[i] = f(i)
    return(cache[i])
```

Then replace every every occurence of `f` with `f_cached`.

There are also libraries out there that can do that for you automatically (with a decorator).

While recursion often yields nice and easy formulas, python is not that good at evaluating them (see tail recursion). You are probably better off with rewriting it in a iterativ way and calculate that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are calculating f[i-1] three times when you can save it's result in some variable and calculate it only once :

```
t = f(i-1)
return t-(1./n)*(1-(1-t)**n)-(1./n)*(t)**n+2.*T/n
```

It will increase the speed of the program, but I would also like to recommend to calculate f without using recursion.

```
fs = T
for i in range(1,N+1):
    tmp = fs
    fs = (tmp-(1./n)*(1-(1-tmp)**n)-(1./n)*(tmp)**n+2.*T/n)
```